# Let $F$ be a subset of a metric space $(X, d)$ such that $\overline{F}$ is compact. Show that $F$ is totally bounded.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $F$ be a subset of a metric space $(X, d)$ such that $\overline{F}$ is compact. Show that $F$ is totally bounded.

---

how can I able to solve this.I have no idea.thanks for your help

Comment: This is a special case of a general theorem in general topology: Any uniform space is totally bounded iff it is precompact (= dense in a compact uniform (super-)space). Any metric space is a uniform space.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $\cl F$ is compact, it is also totally bounded, and there is a finite $A\subseteq\cl F$ such that $\cl F\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in A}B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)$. Let $x\in A$; if $x\in F$, set $x'=x$. Otherwise, $x\in(\cl F)\setminus F$, so there is a point $x'\in F\cap B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)$. Show that $F\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in A}B(x',\epsilon)$, and conclude, since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, that $F$ is totally bounded.

**Added:** The intuition that you should have is something like this. For each $\epsilon>0$ you want to find a finite $A\subseteq F$ such that $F\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in A}B(x,\epsilon)$. You know that $\cl F$ is totally bounded, and $F\subseteq\cl F$, so you might start with a finite $A\subseteq\cl F$ such that $\cl F\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in A}B(x,\epsilon)$. If it happens that $A\subseteq F$, you’re done: this set $A$ works fine. The problem is that some points of $A$ may be in $(\cl F)\setminus F$. Of course those points are limit points of $F$, so they’re ‘very close to’ $F$: we can find points of $F$ as close to them as we want. But no matter how close a point $y$ is to $x$, we can’t guarantee that $B(y,\epsilon)$ will cover every part of $F$ that $B(x,\epsilon)$ covered. There’s a standard trick to handle this problem: we’ll choose $A$ so that **smaller** balls centred at points of $A$ cover $\cl F$. Specifically, I chose $A$ so that the $\frac{\epsilon}2$-balls centred at points of $A$ cover $\cl F$. Now I can move the centre of a ball a little bit, say from $x$ to $x'$, and while $B\left(x',\frac{\epsilon}2\right)$ won’t necessarily cover the same part of $F$ that $B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)$ did, the larger ball $B(x',\epsilon)$ will.

Comment: What a trick. I have never really used this notion. So I proved: $F$ is a totally bounded subset of $X$. But when I read your answer, I understood we were supposed to prove that $(F,d)$ is a totally bounded space, which is stronger. It is maybe trivial, but can you tell me when the notions coincide (like here)?

Comment: @julien: I’d say that they always do, because I understand ‘$F$ is a totally bounded subset of $X$’ to mean that $F$ is totally bounded as a metric subspace. In other words, I understand it to mean that a finite $\epsilon$-net can always be found in $F$.

Comment: According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space) and to what I vaguely recalled, I took: $S$ is a totally bounded subset of $X$ if (and only if, since it is a characterization, not the definition per se) for every $\epsilon>0$, there exist $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ in $X$ such that $S\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^k B(x_j,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @julien: I’d not seen it defined that way before. It doesn’t matter, though: the two notions are equivalent, by the same trick that I used in my answer.

Comment: It seems to me that your trick works because the points $x_j$ of $X$ were  actually already in the closure of the set $F=S$. If we just have $x_j$ in $X$, I don't see how the trick still applies.

Comment: @julien: It works the same way. If $B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)\cap A\ne\varnothing$, pick $x'$ in the intersection, and $B(x',\epsilon)\supseteq B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)$.

Comment: Ah, of course. We just need to drop the useless $x_j$'s first...I'm stupid. Thanks a lot! So once this equivalence is observed, my deleted argument makes it very easy...

Comment: @julien: Yep. One can either prove it, and then feel free to use the superficially weaker version, or simply define *totally bounded subset* to mean *totally bounded subspace* and work a little harder each time.